# I am getting error saying No implicit argument of type:Encoder[ ]" in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I get an error saying No implicit argument of type:Encoder[Movies] can you please tell me where am I going wrong as I am new to spark.

I am trying to read a movies file and converting it to a data set having 1 'ID' column and 2nd 'names of the movie' column.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Practice {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("dataFrameExample")
          .master("local")
          .getOrCreate()

    **case class Movies( ID:String, name:String)**

        val ds1 = spark.read
         .format("text")
         .option("header", "true") //first line in file has headers
         .load("C:\\SparkScala\\SparkScalaStudy\\movies").as[Movies]

        ds1.printSchema()
    }
}
```

Comment: `import Spark.implicits._` right after creating the **SparkSession** as the documentation suggest.

Answer (score 5):

You need to move the `case class Movies` out of the `main` function, and also add `import spark.implicits._` before the `ds1`

Answer (score 1):

You can import the sparksession.implicits to solve the problem or you can write your own implicits in an object as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

object CustomImplicits {    
  implicit val movieEncoder: Encoder[Movies] = Encoders.product[Movies]
}
```

Then simply import the implicit in your main method:

```
import package.containinig.implicits.CustomImplicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object Practice {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("dataFrameExample")
          .master("local")
          .getOrCreate()

        val ds1 = spark.read
         .format("text")
         .option("header", "true") //first line in file has headers
         .load("C:\\SparkScala\\SparkScalaStudy\\movies").as[Movies]

        ds1.printSchema()
    }
}
```

Using the Encoders, you can enforce the Schema on your dataset as it would raise appropriate errors if the Schema is violated.